# how to echo 3 or more array in array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I'm making report table but my array code has more then one array inside my forech can't echo I needed data.

```
foreach($all_data as $key1=> $value1){
     echo $key1 .'<br/>';
        foreach($value1 as $key2 => $value2){
            echo $key2 ;

            if (is_array($value2)){
                foreach($value2 as $key3 => $value3){

                    echo $key3;
                    echo $key3 .'<br/>';
                    foreach($value3 as $key4 => $value4){
                        echo $value4.'<br/>';
                    }
                }
            }else{
                foreach($value2 as $key => $valuess){
                    echo $key .'<br/>';
                }
            }
            echo '<br/>';

        }
    }
```

this is sameple array data I need to make in table.

```
Array
(

    [2012] => Array
        (
            [ifemp] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [if_employed] => No
                            [count(if_employed)] => 1
                        )
                )

            [rk] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [COUNT(*)] => 0
                )

            [pf] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [COUNT(*)] => 0
                )

            [mg] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [COUNT(*)] => 0
                )

            [se] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [COUNT(*)] => 0
                )

            [rg] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [COUNT(*)] => 0
                )

            [ct] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [COUNT(*)] => 0
                )

            [tp] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [COUNT(*)] => 0
                )

            [cs] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [COUNT(*)] => 0
                )

            [se2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [COUNT(*)] => 0
                )

            [skill] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [COUNT(*)] => 0
                )

        )

    [2013] => Array
        (
            [ifemp] => Array
                (
                )

            [rk] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [COUNT(*)] => 0
                )

            [pf] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [COUNT(*)] => 0
                )

            [mg] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [COUNT(*)] => 0
                )

            [se] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [COUNT(*)] => 0
                )

            [rg] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [COUNT(*)] => 0
                )

            [ct] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [COUNT(*)] => 0
                )

            [tp] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [COUNT(*)] => 0
                )

            [cs] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [COUNT(*)] => 0
                )

            [se2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [COUNT(*)] => 0
                )

            [skill] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [COUNT(*)] => 0
                )

        )

    [2014] => Array
        (
            [ifemp] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [if_employed] => Yes
                            [count(if_employed)] => 2
                        )

                )

            [rk] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [COUNT(*)] => 0
                )

            [pf] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [COUNT(*)] => 0
                )

            [mg] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [COUNT(*)] => 1
                )

            [se] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [COUNT(*)] => 0
                )

            [rg] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [COUNT(*)] => 0
                )

            [ct] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [COUNT(*)] => 1
                )

            [tp] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [COUNT(*)] => 0
                )

            [cs] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [COUNT(*)] => 0
                )

            [se2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [COUNT(*)] => 1
                )

            [skill] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [COUNT(*)] => 1
                )
        )
)
```

----------------------------this is sample output I like to make---------------------------------------------------------
Year----Employed--------Unemployed--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2012-----0----------------1---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2013-----0----------------0----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2014-----2----------------0-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Year----Rank/Clerical---Professional/Supervisory--------Managerial/Executive----Selfmployed----------------
2012----0-----------------0--------------------------------------0------------------------------0------------------------------
2013----0-----------------0--------------------------------------0------------------------------0------------------------------
2014----0-----------------0--------------------------------------1------------------------------0------------------------------

Comment: Could you be more specefic? What exactly you want, and what doesn't work?

Comment: you can use `print_r($var);` or `var_dump($var);` to view the contents of an array. `echo print_r($var, true);` can have the second parameter set as true, this will return u a formatted string that can be echo'ed or placed in a log file or whatever! This won't make it appear as per your format.